# using Views_get_view_result to return imagefield contents, but how do I get the path?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

how do I grab images from a node using php? I"m using views_get_view_result to retrieve the array from Views and for the image field I get a serialized string:

a:2:{s:3:"alt";s:20:"south pacific poster";s:5:"title";s:0:"";}

it contains no reference as to where the image is located or the name of the image. In Views the image displays properly in the preview area.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ah! Views has an option for URL to File

Comment: nevermind. The function still doesnt return any information on the imagefield. Only the fid.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell exactly what you are doing, but you can get the filepath from the fid with something like:

```
<?php 
$r = db_result(db_query('select filepath from files where fid=%d',$fid));
```

Comment: I guess I can add all the fids to that one query... I was actually using the drupal function field_file_image. Of course, doing that 50 times would be very inefficient!